# Probability of at least 1 sequence of 6 heads followed by 6 tails among $n$ tosses?

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

You flip a coin $n > 11$ times. What is the probability that you have at least 1 sequence with 6 heads followed by 6 tails.

I am completely lost on how to solve this in an elegant way. The approach that I am thinking of would involve the inclusion-exclusion principle. We'd examine the feasibility of each location in the sequence NOT being the start of the said sequence.

We can define $a_i$ to be the event that the said sequence does not begin at the $i$-th location. Then the probability we're looking for is

$$
1 - P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{N - 11}a_i \right)
$$.

To find $P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{N - 11}a_i \right)$, I believe I would need to invoke the inclusion-exclusion principle, and this will get pretty messy.
Is there a simpler approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the $n$ coin flips end up with $k$ such runs of 12 coin flips. Collapse each run into one slot so that you are thinking in terms of $n-11k$ slots, where $k$ of the slots will expand to be that kind of run of 12. (Note that the runs-of-12 cannot overlap. This problem would need a different solution if, say, we were looking at runs of `THT` that can overlap.)

If $12\leq n<24$, then it's only possible for $k$ to be $1$. You choose which slot to expand, and let the rest be coin flips that fall where they may: $$\frac{\binom{n-11}{1}2^{n-12}}{2^n}$$

Now if $24\leq n<35$, use the same formula, but with inclusion-exclusion to account for when there are two runs of 12 like this: $$\frac{\binom{n-11}{1}2^{n-12}}{2^n}-\frac{\binom{n-22}{2}2^{n-24}}{2^n}$$

Notice that second term is zero for $12\leq n<24$, so its actually a valid formula for $12\leq n<24$ as well.

#### EDIT

The above line is false, I was wrong. For example, something like $\binom{-2}{3}$ is nonzero. It equals $\frac{(-2)(-3)(-4)}{3!}=-4$. So what follows is edited from earlier versions.

Continue in this way with inclusion-exclusion to find $$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/12\rfloor}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\binom{n-11k}{k}2^{n-12k}}{2^n}=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/12\rfloor}(-1)^{k-1}{\binom{n-11k}{k}}2^{-12k}$$

You can even extend this to work for $0\leq n<12$, and simplify to:

$$1-\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/12\rfloor}\left(-2^{-12}\right)^k{\binom{n-11k}{k}}$$

Comment: @user2661923 My answer is a counting argument that never multiplies probabilities, so independence is not a concern. I'm just counting that there are $2^n$ ways for the coin sequence to be flipped for the denominator. And then counting the numerator by counting how many ways there are to just have those runs of 12.

Comment: This would be a harder problem if the runs of 12 could overlap. For example if you were looking for 6H6T _or_ 6T6H. But since they cannot overlap, this works.

Comment: It just hit me.  It is still difficult to comprehend your answer, but I suspect that you are right.  I therefore deleted my comment - very creative.  +1.

Comment: You're right that the answer isn't explained in a crystal clear way. Partly, I just don't have the time. Partly, this feels like some kind of combinatorial homework exercise, and the answer could be just a very strong hint from the OP's perspective.

Comment: When you "collapse" the runs into 1 slot, you state that you end up with $ n - 11k$ potential slots. What I failed to realize is that the runs cannot overlap, so that makes things a lot easier, as you alluded to.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to subtract the two runs of 12 in the $24 \leq n < 35$ case. It seems to suggest the first term is double counting?

Comment: @student010101 Say $n=24$. The first term would count `HHHHHHTTTTTTHHHHHHTTTTTT` twice. Once with the first 12 as the "collapsed" run and the latter 12 just falling that way from coin flipping. And then a second time with the latter 12 as the "collapsed" run. So the second term subtracts one instance where there are two collapsed runs.

Comment: Still trying to process this. Like it 75% makes sense to me, but I could have not come up with this approach.

Comment: For your summation over $k$, why does it go to infinity? It only needs to go to $\lfloor n / 12 \rfloor$ right?

Comment: @student010101 Sure, because all terms after that are $0$. But it looks nicer as $\infty$ than $\lfloor n/12\rfloor$, and perhaps thinking about it with $\infty$ there gives more hope for a closed form expression.

Comment: Is there an approach where you look at this from the "complement" perspective, i.e., finding the probability that there is not a single sequence? Would that be more difficult? Usually, when it comes to "probability of at least 1 something something occurs" type of problems, I typically solve it by finding the complement, i.e., "probability that NO something something occurs" and then taking the complement, and find that to be easier.

Comment: @student010101 I was wrong to sum this to $\infty$. I was working with a very nonstandard convention that $\binom{n}{k}=0$ when $n$ is negative. That is not the standard. So I edited this to stop the sum where you suggested. I'm sorry for the confusion I caused.

Answer (score 1):

The independence approximation should work quite well here. Calling $E_i$ the event that the sequence $(c_i,c_{i+1}\cdots c_{i+11})$ does *not* follow the desired pattern, we have

$$\begin{align}
p_n &= 1 - P(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap \cdots E_{n-11})\\
&\approx  1 - \prod_{i=1}^{n-11} P(E_i)\\
  &=  1-\left(1-\frac{1}{4096}\right)^{n-11}
\end{align}$$

An exact numerical solution can be obtained with Markov chains. The state $s\in \{0,1, 2 \cdots 12\}$ denotes, when $s<12$ the number of matching coins in the tail of the sequence (the desired sequence has not yet appeared); while $s=12$ (absorbing state) means that the desired sequence has already appeared. The transition matrix is given by $P = A/2 $ where $A$ is the following $13 \times 13$ matrix:

```
   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
```

In Matlab/Octave:

```
A = [zeros(12,1),eye(12);zeros(1,13)];
A(1:6,1)=1;
A(8:12,2)=1;
A(7,7)=1;
A(13,13)=2;
P = A/2
p0 = [1,zeros(1,12)]

% prob after 11 tries:
(p0 * P^11) (1,13)
ans = 0
% prob after 12 tries:
(p0 * P^12) (1,13)
ans =  0.00024414
% prob after 13 tries:
(p0 * P^13) (1,13)
ans =  0.00048828
% prob after 24 tries:
(p0 * P^24) (1,13)
ans =  0.0031738
% prob after 50 tries:
(p0 * P^50) (1,13)
ans =  0.0094990
% prob after 200 tries:
(p0 * P^200) (1,13)
ans =  0.045215
% approximation
1-(1-1/4096)^(200-11)
ans =  0.045100
```

Comment: For large $n$, the probability should tend to $1$ because it becomes almost certain that somewhere in the sequence of coin flips is the sough-after run of $12$.

Comment: $(n-11)/2^{12}$ is not even smaller than $1$ for very large $n$.

Comment: @alex.jordan You're right, fixed.

Comment: What is the independence approximation in the first sentence of your answer?

Comment: @student010101 I added some explanation

Comment: Okay, I understand the independence approximation now. But I question its validity. In @alex.jordan answer, we saw that events $E_i$'s are disjoint (well for the most part). $E_i$ would be disjoint of $E_{i+1}, \ldots, E_{i+11}, E_{i - 1}, \ldots, E_{i - 11}$. Since they are disjoint, that means there's a degree of dependence between these events, right? But if $n >> 12$, then the affects of this dependence is mitigated?

Comment: I just compared the exact solution and the approximate solution, and they're nearly identical for small $n$. e.g., for $n = 12$, we have $0.0009762049303354559$ $0.0009765625$ for the approximate and exact solutions, respectively. How is it this accurate? The dependence in my previous comment is very weak?

Comment: For $n=12$ the approximate solution is exact (there is a single event!). The dependence should be weak, because $P(E_i | E_{i-1} E_{i-2} \dots ) \approx P(E_i)$ (knowing that the previous sequences are "bad" tells us little aabout the current sequence being bad). But it's not easy to quantify this.

Comment: Knowing that the present subsequence is `HHHHHHTTTTTT` guarantees the next subsequence is not. So knowing that the present subsequence is not `HHHHHHTTTTTT` slightly increases the chances that the next subsequence is a hit. So I think this is a strong approximation, but not going to give exact results when $n$ is large.

Comment: @alex.jordan You're right. The Markov chain solution is exact, though, and with finite steps.

Comment: By emphasizing "with finite steps" do you mean that my solution is not? It is expressed with $\infty$. But for any $n$, only the first finite number of terms are nonzero. It is also a finite expression. Without any rounding, what is the exact answer you get for $n=24$?

Comment: @alex.jordan, When i tried the exact and non-exact approaches last week, I think I got the two formulas were within like 0.1\% for large and small $n$.

Comment: @alex.jordan No objections. For $n=24$ I get $0.0031737685203552$

Comment: I'm revisiting this problem, and I'm looking at your Markov chain approach. I have a basic understanding of Markov chains. You're trying to compute the probability that you reach the final state in $n$ steps, correct? Where $n$ is the number of coin tosses? What is the formula you use to compute this probability?

Comment: It looks like the formula is $p_0 * P^n$ where $P$ is the transition matrix and $p_0$ is the initial state probabilty vector which is just $[1, 0, \ldots, 0]^T$. I remember seeing this before, I just don't remember how this was derived